# C#のList<T>を非正規化状態にしたい

Tags: c#

例えば、次のクラスのListがあるとします。

```
public class A
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public List<int> Items { get; set; }
        }

List<A> As = new List<A>();
As.Add(new A() { Name = "a", Items = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 } });
            As.Add(new A() { Name = "b", Items = new List<int>() { 1,2,3 } });
            As.Add(new A() { Name = "c", Items = new List<int>() {  } });
```

これをこのようなリスト構造にしたいです。

Itemだけであれば `SelectMany()` を使えばよいのですが、各ItemのNameもほしいです。
C#のLinqでどのように書けばよろしいでしょうか。

| Name | Item |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| a | 3 |
| b | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 4 |
| c | 5 |
| c | 6 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelectManyの[各要素に適用する変換関数](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___)を使用することで実現できます。
[参考資料](https://www.urablog.xyz/entry/2018/05/28/070000#SelectMany%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86)

※ご質問のコードにName="c"のItemsが入っていないのは記入漏れと想定して補完しています。

**サンプルコード**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<A> As = new List<A>();
            As.Add(new A() { Name = "a", Items = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 } });
            As.Add(new A() { Name = "b", Items = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 } });
            As.Add(new A() { Name = "c", Items = new List<int>() { 4, 5, 6 } });
            // SelectManyによる射影変換と平坦化
            var namedAs = As.SelectMany(a => a.Items, (a, i) => new { a.Name, Item = i });
            namedAs.ToList().ForEach(nA => Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Item: {1}", nA.Name, nA.Item));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class A
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<int> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**実行結果**

```
Name: a, Item: 1
Name: a, Item: 2
Name: a, Item: 3
Name: b, Item: 1
Name: b, Item: 2
Name: b, Item: 3
Name: c, Item: 4
Name: c, Item: 5
Name: c, Item: 6
```